# How to get name of caller object in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, callstack

In Oracle, it's complicated to properly get name of caller object when it is wrapped in a package. Here is my attempt to achieve this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function GET_MY_NAME return varchar2 is
  v_owner      varchar2(50);
  v_name       varchar2(50);
  v_lineno     number      ;
  v_caller_t   varchar2(50);
begin
  -- let's determine the object
  owa_util.who_called_me(
    v_owner
  , v_name
  , v_lineno
  , v_caller_t
  );
  dbms_output.put_line(v_caller_t || ' ' || v_owner || '.' || v_name || ' at ' || v_lineno);
  with s as (
    select s.*
         , max(line - 1) over (partition by name order by line rows between 1 following and 1 following) to_line
         , regexp_substr(s.text, '\w+', 1, 2) func_name
      from all_source s
     where s.type  = v_caller_t
       and s.owner = v_owner
       and s.name  = v_name
       and regexp_like(s.text, 'procedure|function')
  )
  select max(nvl(s.func_name, v_name ))
       , max(nvl(s.name     , v_owner))
    into v_name, v_owner
    from s
   where v_lineno between s.line and nvl(s.to_line, 9999999);  
  return v_owner || '.' || v_name;
end;
```

The idea is to determine lines within the source of each inner object is located and take corresponding object. This works fine for packages, but for functions and procedures it cannot determine if it was called from the main block. Here is a little demo:

```
create or replace function check_my_name return varchar2 is
  function sub_check_my_name return varchar2 is
  begin
    return get_my_name;
  end;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(sub_check_my_name);
  return get_my_name;
end;
/
```

You can see that sub_check_my_name works, but direct get_my_name call also returns sub_check_my_name. How can I determine if the call occures inside main function block?

Comment: Oracle has supplied this functionality since at least 10gR2 in [the (admittedly obscure) function `owa_util.who_called_me()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/w_util.htm#i997852) . In 12c they gave us [a whole package, `UTL_CALL_STACK`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/utl-call-stack-12cr1) with a frankly  bewildering range of detail. Which isn't to stop you writing your own implementation for fun. But if this is for work you should use the Oracle built-ins.

Comment: Yep, totally agree. But we are still on 11g. For now, I think it will be enough convenient to use just who_called_me in main block and go further in subprocedures. Hope somebody will find solution for 11g.

Answer (score 0):

I did something as simple as this,

Declared a variable as below,

`call_stack  VARCHAR2(3000) := '';`

Now use the below to get the levels of the calls,

```
FOR j IN REVERSE 1..utl_call_stack.dynamic_depth() LOOP
        call_stack := CASE
            WHEN call_stack IS NOT NULL THEN
                call_stack || '->'
                      END
                      || nvl(utl_call_stack.concatenate_subprogram(utl_call_stack.subprogram(j)), '');
    END LOOP;

dbms_output.put_line(call_stack);
```

This gives the call hierarchy in the call_stack separated by `'->'`